# My PC loses Internet connection from time to time for 30 seconds

Tags: networking, router

When I play games, from time to time I lose Internet connection for about 30 seconds, I check with my browser and it doesn't load pages also.

I thought this might be because I'm using a dumb setup at home going through 2 routers, but checking their logs it seems they were up while I didn't have connection.

Can you verify that the routers where running with no problem at the time?

Time of connection loss - 15:45

Router 1 Log (first in chain)

```
May 14 12:22:21  pppd[60]: Connect time 1440.2 minutes.
May 14 12:22:21  pppd[60]: Sent 4139364793 bytes, received 4172474857 bytes.
May 14 12:22:23  ntp client: time is synchronized to time.nist.gov pool.ntp.org 
May 14 12:22:51  pppd[60]: Starting link
May 14 12:22:51  pppd[60]: PPP session is 290
May 14 12:22:54  pppd[60]: CHAP authentication succeeded
May 14 12:22:54  PPPoE: connect to ISP
```

Router 2 Log (second in chain)

```
194 May 14 14:25:17 DHCP    NOTICE  DHCPS:Send ACK to 192.168.0.102
193 May 14 14:25:17 DHCP    NOTICE  DHCPS:Recv REQUEST from [hidden MAC]
192 May 14 13:25:17 DHCP    NOTICE  DHCPS:Send ACK to 192.168.0.102
191 May 14 13:25:17 DHCP    NOTICE  DHCPS:Recv REQUEST from [hidden MAC]
190 May 14 12:25:16 DHCP    NOTICE  DHCPS:Send ACK to 192.168.0.102
189 May 14 12:25:16 DHCP    NOTICE  DHCPS:Recv REQUEST from [hidden MAC]
188 May 14 12:25:16 DHCP    NOTICE  DHCPS:Send OFFER with ip 192.168.0.102
187 May 14 12:25:15 DHCP    NOTICE  DHCPS:Recv DISCOVER from [hidden MAC]
```

From what I understand my computer was sending multiple request to the second router asking to connect, that means that it lost connection for some reason no?

If I'm correct that means that the problem is in my computer. How can I discover what causes this?

I'm on Windows 8.1

P.S. I've no antivirus/malware/firewall software - I install them once every couple of months to clean and uninstall.

Comment: I know it's not the focus of the question, but you should always have an up to date anti virus application installed. Use a low resource one like avast or even MSE but if you don't have one and get a nasty trojan, no amount of 'cleaning' will help. Prevention is key to protection.

Comment: I would check that only one router is giving out DHCP addresses - two will give you all sorts of conflicts